Proof that quasi-isomorphisms form a localizing class in the homotopy category of complexes
I'm currently reading Gelfand and Manin's book Methods of Homological Algebra. Theorem III.4.4 says that the class of quasi-isomorphism in a homotopy category of complexes is localizing and I am having trouble following one particular claim.
First some terminology: Given a map of complexes $f:K^\bullet\to L^\bullet$ in an abelian category $\mathcal{A}$, the cone of $f$ is the complex $C(f)$ defined by
$$
C(f)^{i} = K^{i+1}\oplus L^{i}, \quad d_{C(f)} = \begin{pmatrix} -d_K & 0\\ f & d_L \end{pmatrix},
$$
and the cylinder of $f$ is the complex $\mathrm{Cyl}(f)$ defined by
$$
\mathrm{Cyl}(f)^{i} = K^{i}\oplus K^{i+1}\oplus L^{i}, \quad d_{\mathrm{Cyl}(f)} = \begin{pmatrix} d_k & -\mathrm{id}_K & 0 \\
0 & -d_K & 0\\
0 & f & d_L \end{pmatrix}.
$$
We have a sequence (called a triangle) in the homotopy category $K^*(\mathcal{A})$ of complexes (where $*=\varnothing,+,-,b$)
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
K^\bullet @>{\overline{f}}>> \mathrm{Cyl}(f) @>{\pi}>> C(f) @>{\delta(f)}>> K[1]^\bullet
\end{CD}
$$
where $\overline{f}$ is the inclusion in the first summand, $\pi$ is the projection onto the last two summands and $\delta(f)$ is the projection onto the first summand, and a distinguisehd triangle is any sequence isomorphic to a triangle of this form. It is easy to prove that
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
K^\bullet @>{f}>> L^\bullet @>{\overline{\pi}}>> C(f) @>{\delta(f)}>> K[1], \tag{1}\label{eq1}
\end{CD}
$$
where $\overline{\pi}$ is the inclusion into the second summand, is a distiguished triangle.
Now, in the proof of Theorem III.4.4, they must verify the conditions of the definition of a localizing class. One of them is the extension condition (called the Ore condition by another authors), which says that a diagram
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
K^\bullet @>{f}>{qis}> L^\bullet @<{g}<< M^\bullet
\end{CD}
$$
(the qis next to an arrow means that the arrow is a quasi-isomorphism) can be embedded in a commutative diagram
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
N^\bullet @>{k}>{qis}> M^\bullet\\
@V{h}VV @VV{g}V\\
K^\bullet @>f>{qis}> L^\bullet
\end{CD}.
$$
For this, they use a particular diagram, but what I don't understand is the claim that
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
C(\overline{\pi}g)[-1] @>{k}>> M^\bullet @>{\overline{\pi}g}>> C(f) @>>> C(\overline{\pi}g)
\end{CD} \tag{2}\label{eq2}
$$
is a distinguished triangle, where $k=\delta(\overline{\pi}g)[-1]$.
I tried to prove that this triangle is isomorphic to
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
C(\overline{\pi}g)[-1] @>{k}>> M^\bullet @>{\rho}>> C(k) @>>> C(\overline{\pi}g)
\end{CD}
$$
where $\rho$ is the inclusion into the third summand, which is distinguished as it is of the form \eqref{eq1}, but any "vertical" morphisms I tried to find such a isomorphism fail to commute up to homotopy.
So my question is: how to prove that \eqref{eq2} is a distinguished triangle?

Note that if we write $(2)$ as $X\overset{a}{\to}Y\overset{b}{\to}Z\overset{c}{\to}\Sigma X$ then this is distinguished if and only if its shift $Y\overset{b}{\to}Z\overset{c}{\to}\Sigma X\overset{-\Sigma a}{\to}\Sigma Y$ is distinguished, by one of the axioms of a triangulated category (and I here assume your authors have already verified the homotopy category of complexes is triangulated). But the shift here is the canonical triangle of the cone of the morphism $\overline{\pi}g$, so it is distinguished.
Well, that is, modulo a sign issue. I'm not exactly sure of your sign conventions, but if you mean by $k=\delta(\overline{\pi}g)[-1]$ that $k_n=-\delta(\overline{\pi}g)_{n-1}$ then this works. Or else we would have to alter the inclusion $C(f)\to C(\overline{\pi}g)$ by a sign. This is because negative $\Sigma a$ appears there.

Thanks! Actually the authors do not introduce triangulated categories until the next chapter, but now I can write a more elementary proof by mimicking the proof of the axiom in this context.
